# Facebook Graph API Groups

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I try get information about own groups over [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/).
On me/groups I get list of groups. But I not understood what is params: **bookmark_order**.

Also we can see param **unread**:1. If I right, it present if another user set some change in group (post new comment). If I refresh group page in browser or open in native android [app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.facebook.katana&feature=search_result), then **unread** is no longer appears. After which api request I can remove unread flag?

Also at group's wall I can ask question. But {group_id}/feed not contain this posts. How I can get it?

I have group document. I can get data about this document: subject, message. But if in document I insert image, then in message param I has string about this image: (img:301666969868743). How can I get this image? Simple GET-request with 301666969868743 (I assumed that this long decimal is ID) return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bookmark_order** (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

> An array of objects containing the version(old-0 or new Group-1),
>   name, id, administrator (if user is the administrator of the Group)
>   and bookmark_order(at what place in the list of group bookmarks on the
>   homepage, the group shows up for the user).

**unread**

Doesn't appear to be documented.  I would presume this would be a read-only value that facebook controls.

Log a documentation bug with facebook and ask them to explain it. (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=search&search_ids%5B0%5D=208685622513742)

**question not appearing in {group_id}/feed**

Tested it and you're right, it doesn't appear. Good find. You should log this as a bug with facebook.
 (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

**Group document with image**

When I did an image in a document, I too got the cryptic (img:###) inside the message of the returned object from `{group_id}/docs`.  However I was able to find it on the graph using `https://graph.facebook.com/####?access_token=@@@@`  and it returned the results.  So I'm not sure how to help you with this one

Comment: DMCS, thanks.
Some about unread. I reseach facebook android application and find, that it mark as readed group with POST request and param: **viewed=true**. But I get: _"(#200) Requires extended permission: manage_groups"_. I've seen this issue by another people. And until this bug not fix, we nothing todo. Just sad, that native facebook application work correct.

Comment: Interested about image in group document.
I try get picture URL from [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and has problem. But I also try this from another user (user, who posted this image). And yahoo! All ok.
I could be wrong, but I think, that problem appear, because this image (but not matter who created document) posted by another user. And by owner user I get normal result. From another (although another user also consist in group) - error.
It would be cool, if you check this situation

Comment: You've gotta remember the native facebook app doesn't use a public API, they're using their own API not available to third party devs.  So of course they're going to have more functionality.  Did you log it as a bug?  Can you post the link to your bug report?

Comment: Picture in group document issue, if your issue is reproducible, you should log it as a bug.  Please post that bug report link here.

Comment: Hm, I add one bug about document's image, but set option confidential...
I think that only App, IDs will be hide, but facebook hide all bug

Comment: Another question. Group can has some documents. Each document we can like and add comment. How get count of likes? If I send {group_doc_id}/likes I get list of users. Of couse, I can calc it's count. But also count can be greater. Then I need send request by request (pagging) not yet counted all users. But may be present more simply way?